# Symfony2 custom password encoder and password hash update

Tags: wordpress, symfony, passwords, bcrypt, encoder

I'm learning Symfony2 by moving some wordpress blog to Symfony. I'm stuck with login procedure. Wordpress uses non standard password hashing like `$P$....` and I want to check users against old password hash when they login and when password is correct, rehash it to bcrypt. So far I created custome encoder class to use with symfony security mechanism.

```
<?php
namespace Pkr\BlogUserBundle\Service\Encoder;

use PHPassLib\Application\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;

class WpTransitionalEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{

    public function __construct($cost = 13)
    {
        $secure = new SecureRandom();
        $this->_bcryptEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder($secure, $cost);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        if (preg_match('^\$P\$', $encoded)) {
            $context = new Context();
            $context->addConfig('portable');
            return $context->verify($raw, $encoded);
        }
        return $this->_bcryptEncoder->isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt);
    }

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return $this->_bcryptEncoder->encodePassword($raw, $salt);
    }
}
```

I'm using it as a service:

```
#/src/Pkr/BlogUserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    pkr_blog_user.wp_transitional_encoder:
        class: Pkr\BlogUserBundle\Service\Encoder\WpTransitionalEncoder
```

And in security.yml:

```
#/app/config/security.yml
security:
encoders:
    Pkr\BlogUserBoundle\Entity\User:
        id:   pkr_blog_user.wp_transitional_encoder
        cost: 15
```

My questions are:

**How do I pass parameters to my encoder service form within `security.yml`?**

I'm asking because `cost: 15` does not work.

**Where should I put password hash update logic? I was thinking that maby just after password validation something like this:**

```
public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
{
    if (preg_match('^\$P\$', $encoded)) {
        $context = new Context();
        $context->addConfig('portable');
        $isValid = $context->verify($raw, $encoded);
        if ($isValid) {
            // put logic here...
        }
        return $isValid;
    }
    return $this->_bcryptEncoder->isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt);
}
```

but it seem somehow like wrong place for it. So what is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

I placed parameters for my encoder service inside `config.yml`

```
pkr_blog_user:
    password_encoder:
        cost: 17
```

They will be passed to my bundle extension class:

```
# /src/Pkr/BlogUserBundle/DependencyInjection/PkrBlogUserExtension.php
namespace Pkr\BlogUserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
* This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
*
* To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
*/
class PkrBlogUserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        if ($config['password_encoder']['cost'] < 10) {
            $config['password_encoder']['cost'] = sprintf('%02d', $config['password_encoder']['cost']);
        }
        $container->setParameter('pkr_blog_user.wp_transitional_encoder.cost', $config['password_encoder']['cost']);

    }
}
```

I found out that I could use my own authentication success handler so there is a good place to put password rehash logic. Unfortunately when using custom handler symfony2 won't pass config to class constructor but I found a way to make it work. I described it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988399/1089412